# How can I convert this PowerShell script to create a simple URL in to C# code?

Tags: c#, powershell, active-directory

I spent time creating this in PowerShell only to realize I need to do this in C# with a simple EXE that will create this URL and launch the browser to that URL. Basically it's grabbing the locally logged in users email address from AD and their computer name and submitting it to another form with JSON.

```
    $email = ([adsi]"LDAP://$(whoami /fqdn)").mail  
    $workstation =  $env:computername

    $url = 'https://www.cognitoforms.com/SupportRequestForm?entry={{"CreateSupportTicket":{{"Workstation":"{0}","YourEmailAddress":"{1}","ConfirmEmail":"{1}"}}}}' -f $workstation, $email.value
```

Could someone help me out in converting this to C#?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have Active Directory installed here for testing but I hope this help. For starters add a reference to `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` in References node of Solution Explorer before including `using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;` in your code. Then try this code:

```
string email = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;
string url = string.Format("https://www.cognitoforms.com/SupportRequestForm?entry={{\"CreateSupportTicket\":{{\"Workstation\":\"{0}\",\"YourEmailAddress\":\"{1}\",\"ConfirmEmail\":\"{1}\"}}}}", Environment.MachineName, email);
Console.WriteLine(url);
```

If you need fqdn use this:

```
string fdqn = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Environment.MachineName).HostName;
```